# How to define priority for each column and then show the results order by that priority?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// tablename
+----+---------+-----------------------+
| id | subject |        context        |
+----+---------+-----------------------+
| 1  |  ali    |    hello              |
| 2  |  peter  |    what's up jack     |
| 3  |  jack   |    have fun           |
+----+---------+-----------------------+
```

The *type* of `subject` is `varchar` and `context` is `text`.

Now I need to a query for search in two columns, both `subject` and `context`. So I have an index like this: `fulltext(subject,context)` and here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (subject,context) AGAINST ($var) limit 10;
```

Now my question is about **the sort of result**: (suppose `$var = 'jack'`), So there is two result (`id=2` (in the `context` column), `id=3` (in the `subject` column)). Now, first, I want to show all the result of `subject` column and then show the result of `context` column. In other word I want this output:

```
+----+---------+-----------------------+
| 3  |  jack   |    have fun           |
| 2  |  peter  |    what's up jack     |
+----+---------+-----------------------+
```

So how can I use `order by` in my sql for implementing something like this?

Comment: Ordering columns is not done via order by, but the order of the fields in the select clause of the query: select id, subject, content from table ... order by is for ordering records.

Answer (score 0):

You could just

```
ORDER BY subject
```

to sort by the subject.

If you want a custom sort, you would do something like:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject = 'Jack' THEN 1
              WHEN subject = 'Ali' THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END, subject
```

This will always put Jack at the top followed by Ali, then the rest will be sorted by **subject**.

**For your scenario**, just change it a little:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject = $var THEN 1
              WHEN context = $var THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END, subject
```

You might need to use CHARINDEX to find your variable:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CHARINDEX ($var, subject) > 0 THEN 1
              WHEN CHARINDEX ($var, context) > 0 THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END, subject
```

Comment: What?! I use fulltext, so I have not something like `column='value'`, I have `MATCH() AGAINST()`. also I need to search in the `context` column, not just `subject` column.

Comment: I have expanded the theory a little.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.
I just tried the same in Oracle with following query. I can order by asc or desc by specifying sort order. I think the same can be achieved in mysql as well as suggested by [han](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4459617/hannover-fist)

```
SELECT * FROM employees where subject like '%jack%' or context like '%jack%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject like '%jack%' THEN 1
              ELSE 2 END, subject;
```